# graphing exponential function

Tags: graphing-functions

When graphing a function with exponentials in the numerator and denominator if you know its defined for all $x$ in $R$, can you do anything more than check the limits as it approaches positive and negative infinity and then check a point like x=0 and then just give it a go at graphing it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, check for when $y=0$

Comment: Whoa, slow down there. What exactly do you want to graph?

Comment: Such a function is graphed like others, by finding special points and asymptotic behavior, and studying variations.

Comment: Thanks  for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are over simplifying the problem of graphs involving  exponential functions.

May be your method works for some simple functions like logistic equations but it can get more complicated than just checking the end behavior and the intercepts.